Vue JS 3 Composables Good Practices
I am here because I'm trying to learn the good practices when it comes to vue.js composables. 
For some context: I am developing an app that use Firebase firestore and auth I created 2 composables:

one for authenticating a user (that I named useAuth)
one for creating user in the firestore (that I named useUser)

The "useAuth" call the "useUser" when the authentication completed and the update my store state. And I was wondering if this flow is good or really bad? Another thing I wanted to know is if I can pass data in my composable function? Like "useAuth(someData)". The question comes because I think it's a real pain to mock Firebase system and I want to inject some service inside my composable, but I read somewhere that is not a good idea because if a bug happens it could be hard to find the cause?
Here the code I've write:
useAuth.ts
import { ref } from 'vue'

import { auth } from '@/modules/repository/implementation/firebase/firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useAuthStore } from '@/stores/auth'
import type User from '@/modules/model/User'
import { useUser } from './useUser'

export const useAuth = () => {
  const { login } = useAuthStore()
  const { getUserByEmail, addUser } = useUser()

  const error = ref<string>()

  const onLogin = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      const cred = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      const user = await getUserByEmail(email)
      if (user) {
        login(user)
        return true
      }
      error.value = 'The user should connect but no data found for it'
      return false
    } catch (err) {
      if ((err as any)?.code === 'auth/invalid-credential') {
        error.value = 'No user were found for the given credentials'
      } else if ((err as any)?.name === 'FirebaseError') {
        error.value = 'An error occured with an external service'
      } else {
        error.value = 'An unknow error occured'
      }
      return false
    }
  }

  const onRegister = async (user: User) => {
    try {
      const userCred = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.email, user.password)
      login(await addUser(user, userCred.user.uid))
      return true
    } catch (err) {
      if ((err as any)?.name === 'FirebaseError') {
        error.value = 'An error occured with an external service'
      } else {
        error.value = 'An unknow error occured'
      }
      return false
    }
  }

  return { error, onLogin, onRegister }
}

useUser.ts
import User from '@/modules/model/User'
import { usersCollection } from '@/modules/repository/implementation/firebase/firebase'
import { doc, getDocs, query, setDoc, where } from 'firebase/firestore'

export const useUser = () => {
  const getUserByEmail = async (email: string): Promise<User | null> => {
    const userDoc = (await getDocs(query(usersCollection, where('email', '==', email)))).docs[0]
    if (userDoc) {
      return {
        ...(userDoc.data() as User),
        uid: userDoc.id
      }
    }
    return null
  }

  const addUser = async (user: User, userId: string): Promise<User> => {
    const createdDoc = await doc(usersCollection, userId)
    const userToAdd = { ...user, uid: userId }
    await setDoc(createdDoc, userToAdd)
    return userToAdd
  }

  return { getUserByEmail, addUser }
}

PS: I make some research before asking, but I didn't find something that helps me.
At first I wrote some service and inject them, but after some research I thought that using composable goes better with vue js composition.

i would say a composable should use component hooks, if not it's not a composable but rather a singleton service. it seems you have just a service if it's application-wide. if you need to auth and log out in a component then a composable (it should use onUnmounted hook)

What you describe is "bad". The question isn't constructive in general, it's specific to your case. Please, provide code instead of describing it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , so it could be specifically addressed. You could DI with several methods, including Vue's own provide/inject. Testing is generally not a problem because modern test runners (Jest, Vitest) mock at module level, you rarely ever need to explicitly implement DI for this purpose.

It's unclear why is there a separation between useAuth and useAuthStore. It makes sense for a store to contain all logic it's responsible for. And useUser is not actually a composable because it doesn't use composition api and it doesn't really need to be a function, so the question asked about wrong thing. You could call it "user service" and export addUser, etc from the module. It could be a class or factory function, but it's stateless, so no need for this. If you care about testability , you can mock it at module level. You'll need to mock firebase api only when testing the service itself

@EstusFlask I understand that the use of the "useUser" is not necessary at all. So, can I create a service that I will provide in the useAuth method? Like this "useAuth(provide("myUserService")"?
And for the useAuthStore and useAuth, I separate them because the store is there for storing the connected user data and the other is just here for authenticating the user.
That certainly means that my useAuth have to be a class too. Even though, can I do the provide inside the composable function call?

No, you can just import myUserService from its module. No need for "provide". You can mock the whole module in tests if testability is your concern. "the store is there for storing the connected user data and the other is just here for authenticating the user" - usually there's no need for separation, since both deal with "user" entity, a "store" isn't just glorified global state, it can contain logic. I'd move all FB calls to the "service" to abstract them away, so it could be mocked in tests (currently useAuth contains FB calls, which won't help you). And leave the rest in a store.

On the other hand, if you want "error" to be local rather than global state, this would be a proper case for additional composable, but you could just return/throw an error from store method instead of error ref

Yes I wanted to make it easy to test and I though that providing a service through injection will make it easier.
So, if I correctly understood,
I can move the auth logic inside a service that i will import and use in my store?

@CyrilAuquier This was the recommended approach at some point (e.g. Angular testing), but totally unnecessary here. The whole service can be mocked with jest.mock in tests. It's possible to use provide/inject, but unless you intend to use SSR with server-side auth and have separate service instance per app instance, this would be overengineering here. Yes, I'd expect that the logic between the store and service is separated in a way the service is expected fully mocked, i.e. it contains all firebase calls that shouldn't happen

@EstusFlask Okay thank you, I see how I can make it better
Can you just post an answer so I can accept it?

Yes, I will post it. I noticed that you didn't explicitly mention testing in "mock Firebase system". Was this only about testing indeed?

Actually, it was a little bit about testing but a great part was about doing composable the right way


The "useAuth" call the "useUser" when the authentication completed and the update my store state. And I was wondering if this flow is good or really bad?

It is totally okay to call a composable inside a composable.
The docs say:

"In the context of Vue applications, a "composable" is a function that leverages Vue's Composition API to encapsulate and reuse stateful logic."


Another thing I wanted to know is if I can pass data in my composable function? Like "useAuth(someData)".

Yes you also can do this, like described in the docs:
https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables#input-arguments
Generally I would recommend to read the Vue docs a lot. Nearly everything is really well documented. Hope it helps.

This is specific to actual code, which the OP didn't show. A composable should be called in the body of component setup, directly or not. This "call the "useUser" when the authentication completed" suggests that it's called asynchronously, which is a mistake, so it's not ok

@EstusFlask i've updated the question to provide the code that i've described.
And yes the operation is asynchrounous but i didn't understand how i can make it not asynchrounous wich is why it is like that

I could inject a service inside the composable function?
I ask it even if I have the feeling that it is not a good idea and that it will probably not goes well with the compsable function.

@CyrilAuquier The code you provided is actually ok in this regard. Despite what the question says, you call useUser instantly but use it asynchronously, this is how composables are supposed to work. useUser is not really a composable as noted in another comment, but that's a different story
